# Auto adjust jqgrid column width according to table grid width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid with 2 columns. The following is the column model:

```
colModel.append("{name:\"group_id\",index:\"GOID\",width:80,sortable:true,align:\"left\", formatter:linkFormat, unformat:unformatLink}\n")
        .append(",{name:\"group_name\",index:\"GNAME\",width:350,sortable:true,align:\"left\", formatter:formatHtml, unformat:unformatHtml}");
```

The table grid width is 95% and changes according to the window size.

Now I need to auto adjust two of the columns widths to fill the entire grid. I dont want to show empty space at the end of the grid.

Comment: Do you have shrinktofit disabled (ie false) in the grid, by default it should be enabled and take care of this for you.

Answer (score 5):

Since what was mentioned in the comments worked, I will add this answer for completeness. According to the [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) for jqGrid for auto adjustment of columns you can use the [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) `shrinktofit:true`.

According to the wiki `ShrinkToFit` does the following:

> This option, if set, defines how the the width of the columns of the
>   grid should be re-calculated, taking into consideration the width of
>   the grid. If this value is true, and the width of the columns is also
>   set, then every column is scaled in proportion to its width. For
>   example, if we define two columns with widths 80 and 120 pixels, but
>   want the grid to have a width of 300 pixels, then the columns will
>   stretch to fit the entire grid, and the extra width assigned to them
>   will depend on the width of the columns themselves and the extra width
>   available. The re-calculation is done as follows: the first column
>   gets the width (300(new width)/200(sum of all widths))*80(first column
>   width) = 120 pixels, and the second column gets the width (300(new
>   width)/200(sum of all widths))*120(second column width) = 180 pixels.
>   Now the widths of the columns sum up to 300 pixels, which is the width
>   of the grid. If the value is false and the value in width option is
>   set, then no re-sizing happens whatsoever. So in this example, if
>   shrinkToFit is set to false, column one will have a width of 80
>   pixels, column two will have a width of 120 pixels and the grid will
>   retain the width of 300 pixels. If the value of shrinkToFit is an
>   integer, the width is calculated according to it.  - The effect of
>   using an integer can be elaborated.